# Fetch post with body data not working params empty

Tags: ajax, fetch

I am trying to rewrite my ajax call to fetch:

Ajax:

```
  $.post({
    context: this,
    url: "/api/v1/users",
    data: { 
      user: 
        {
          email: email,
          password: password
        } 
    }
  }).done((user) => {
  }).fail((error) => {
  })
```

Fetch:

```
  fetch('/api/v1/users', {  
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },      
    body: { 
    "user" : 
      {
        "email" : email,
        "password" : password
      } 
  }
  })
  .then(res => {  
    if (res.status !== 200) { {
        console.log("error")
      })          
    } else {
      res.json().then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
    }
  })
```

I am getting an error empty params ~ bad request from my server.

I also found this way to do it, but in this code below I am getting an error: Unexpected token.

```
  var payload = { 
    "user" : 
      {
        "email" : email,
        "password" : password
      } 
  };

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

  fetch('/api/v1/users', {  
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },      
    body: data
  })
```

How can I rewrite the ajax request to fetch?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Followed this topic on github: https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/34

The solution to my question is using the JSON.stringify function and set Content-Type header to application/json. Not pretty sure why the second attempt in my question didn't work though.

```
fetch('/api/v1/users', {  
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({ "user": {
      "email" : email,
      "password" : password
    }}),
})
```

Official MDN Documentation:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

fetch('/contact-form', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default',
    body: JSON.stringify(fields)
}).then(() => {
    dispatch(contactFormSubmitSuccess());
});
```

Comment: (it fails in chrome, instead this, i'm make encode params to url)

Comment: Adding headers as Dudis suggested worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me, `fetch` is still doing a `get` instead of post!

Answer (score 21):

**TL;DR Without `mode: 'cors'` your JSON body won't go through.**

I wrestled with this for a bit. `cors` was the issue. Assuming you are performing a request from one domain to another (i.e. from `localhost:8080` to `localhost:3000`) you need to have `mode: 'cors'` in the fetch settings & your receiving domain (`localhost:3000`) needs to allow requests from the sending domain (`localhost:8080`).

So the above description in code:

**request from `localhost:8080` to `localhost:3000`**

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors', // this cannot be 'no-cors'
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "user": {
          "email": `${this.state.userEmail}`,
          "password": `${this.state.userPass}`
        }
      }),
    })
```

And then make sure your receiving domain `localhost:3000` allows CORS from `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 15):

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

already answered

Comment: yeah, can not stress the header enough. I spent way too long confused, when the issue was me misspelling application in the header. First step is to check for typos.

Comment: That literally happened to me too with the exact same fetch functionality. Can stress what Jacob C. said enough. Typos people!

Comment: for me it was 'header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}'. bloody typos

Comment: without an s, it just cost you another day. :(

Answer (score 9):

Worked in this way when sending `body` as `json` failed.

```
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('key1', 'value1');
        formData.append('key1', 'value2');

        fetch('url', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: formData
        }`)`
```

In my case, the server only identified the content through the form-data submission. The code was not written to read the request body as json. So there is a possibility to have an issue with your server side code as well.

Comment: after lot of struggle the above method worked for me. thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using an Express server to handle the requests, make sure you add in this line:

```js
app.use(express.json({limit:'1mb'}))
```

Answer (score 5):

The only thing working for me was to put

`app.use(express.json())`

in my main server file.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
fetch('/api/v1/users', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({"user":{
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    }}),
});
```

[fetch API](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

Comment: Thanks, it's basically the same like my second example in my question. It's still showing me params missing although the ajax version works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting (body-parser) at the top of your app.js / server.js :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fetch does not work with no-cors.
So you should set mode on cors like this:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

const Params = {
  key: value,  // replace this by your data key and value
};

await fetch( "url_here",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "default",
    body: JSON.stringify(Params),
 }
).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) =>
    console.log(data)
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```